# How to unit test instance method - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I am looking to structure my unit tests in the correct way and would like to know how to approach testing a class method while passing an object into the method

So the method in question (basic example)

MyClient.m:

```
#import "MyClient.h"

@interface MyClient()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) MyMedia *myMedia;
@end

- (void)setMedia:(MyMedia *)media {
    self.MyMedia = media;
     int var;
    if (media && media.isLive) {
      var = 1;
    }
    else {
      var = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

So in this example i would create two tests, 1 that tests var is 2 if media.isLive and the other to check var is 2 if not.

Hopefully this makes sense

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand. You're asking about a class method, but your code doesn't have one. A class method would be prefixed with +; instance methods are prefixed with -. Also, that function is `void`; you can't return values from it.

Comment: Apologies, you are right, got a bit mixed up there, I've updated my question which hopefully now makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really testable because everything you would need to check is private. Whilst there are ways to 'hack' into a class using the runtime and stuff to test things, you really want to just utilise the publically access interface of your class. So I've re-written your code like this:

MyClient.h

```
@interface MyClient:NSObject 
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MyMedia *myMedia;
    @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) int var;
@end
```

MyClient.m

```
#import "MyClient.h"

@implementation MyClient

- (void)setMedia:(MyMedia *)media {
    _MyMedia = media;
    _var = media && media.isLive ? 1 : 2;
}

@end
```

Now lets do some tests using XCTest.

MyClientTests.m

```
@import XCTest;
#import "MyClient.h"

@interface MyClienTests:XCTestCase
@end

@implementation MyClientTests {
    MyClient *_myCLient;
    MyMedia *_media;
}

-(void) setUp {
    _myClient = [[MyClient alloc] init];
    _media = [[MyMedia alloc] init];
}

-(void) testMyClientMediaIsAlive {
    _media.alive = YES;
    _myClient.media = _media;
    XCTAssertEqual(1, _myClient.var);
}

-(void) testMyClientMediaIsNotAlive {
    _myClient.media = _media;
    XCTAssertEqual(2, _myClient.var);
}

-(void) testMyClientNoMedia {
    XCTAssertEqual(2, _myClient.var);
}

@end
```